# What are the real risks of using fsync off on postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I read [this email post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2006-04/msg00632.php), but I couldn't really understand what is the real risk.

In case of failure, can it recover from it self or will it force us to use a backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a failure, you have to restore your database from a backup.  It will not (in general) recover by itself.